# Newtype pattern error: cannot move out of dereference of

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, dereference

I want to create a Wrapper around an existing type/struct. According to the Newtype pattern, as per Rust Book ch 19, "implementing Deref trait on the Wrapper to return an inner type would give access to all the underlying methods":

https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html

Here is my implementation on a wrapper around a String. A simplified example:

```rust
struct Wrapper(String);

impl Deref for Wrapper {
    type Target = String;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.0 //pointer to Inner value
    }
}
```

However, calling a method which consumes self throws an error:

```rust
fn main() {
    let d = "Dog".to_string();
    let w = Wrapper(d);
    w.into_bytes();
}
```

Error: **cannot move out of dereference of `Wrapper` move occurs because value has type `std::string::String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait**

Therefore I have two questions:

1. What is wrong with my implementation and how do make it work?
2. I'd like to make it work properly with self, &self, mut self, &mut self methods. How do I also implement DerefMut appropriately?

Comment: Don't implement `Deref` for newtypes. `Deref` should only be implemented for smart pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is wrong with my implementation and how do make it work?

[`String::into_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.into_bytes) moves the `String`, in your case you only have access to a reference of it `&`, so you cannot move it.

You could use [`bytes`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f3a105277f05ec58811e73adbdcc6c72) which returns an iterator to the bytes without moving it:

```rust
fn main() {
    let d = "Dog".to_string();
    let w = Wrapper(d);
    let b = w.bytes();
    println!("{b:?}");
}
```

> I'd like to make it work properly with self, &self, mut self, &mut self methods. How do I also implement DerefMut appropriately?

You need to take into account the signatures, in general:

- `Deref` -> Get a `&T`
- `DerefMut` -> Get a `&mut`
- `From/Into` -> Transform the type into an owned version of other type `T`

Example using `From/Into`:

```rust
struct Wrapper(String);

impl From<Wrapper> for String {
    fn from(w: Wrapper) -> String {
        w.0
    }
}

fn main() {
    let d = "Dog".to_string();
    let w = Wrapper(d);
    let s: String = w.into();
    let bytes = s.into_bytes();
    println!("{bytes:?}");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=146ba596b985c4a893339d83c507bb45)

You could also consider taking a look at the [`std::borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/index.html) module, which has the traits that allow you to use your types as other types.

Finally, your approach may work, but as explained before, you cannot go from `&T` to `U` in this case (you could `T` to `U`). The remaining solution is to `Clone` and create an owned copy:

```rust
use std::ops::Deref;

struct Wrapper(String);

impl Deref for Wrapper {
    type Target = String;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.0 //pointer to Inner value
    }
}

fn main() {
    let d = "Dog".to_string();
    let w = Wrapper(d);
    let b = w.deref().clone().into_bytes();
    println!("{b:?}");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d12a295f5dcbe0055f06697dddcbe250)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This was just as a simplified example, I am in fact not even writing a wrapper around String, but another type. I am more conserned about the general solution rather than a workaround.